# How to continue when no_data_found exception raised?

Tags: oracle, plsql

I have a value that i dont know exactly in which column it is inserted. I can determine that since this table columns are named as C1....C99. I am going to find the column using the following code. **But when the no data found exception is called, I cant start my loop again.**

```
DECLARE
   i number:=1;
   k boolean := true;
   output number;
   stmt varchar(500);
BEGIN
  <<repeat>>
  while(k)
  loop
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE( 'c column -->'||i );
   EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'select 1 from X_TAB t where t.c'||i||'= ''NOTE_NFE'''

     into output;
     IF output = 1 then
        DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE( 'c column'||i );
        k:=false;
     END IF;
     i:=i+1;
     IF i = 100 then
        k:=false;
     END IF;
END LOOP;
EXCEPTION 
     when no_data_found then
       i:=i+1;
       if i = 100 then
          k:=false;
       end if;
       goto repeat;
END;
/
```

Comment: Hopefully this is an exercise to demonstrate to you precisely *why* it's a Really Bad Idea to have repeated columns like in a table.

Comment: if you have more than 1 row returned you'll also have an exception.  I think you want select count(1) instead of select 1.  Also, damn that table schema, wow.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think that moving your try catch to inside the loop will do the trick for you.

```
DECLARE
   i number:=1;
   k boolean := true;
   output number;
   stmt varchar(500);
BEGIN
  <<repeat>>
  while(k)
  loop
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE( 'c column -->'||i );
    begin
       EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'select 1 from X_TAB t where t.c'||i||'= ''FISCAL_NOTE_NFE''' into output;
    exception when no_data_found then
          output := 0; --set a default value
          dbms_output.put_line('no data found.');
    end;
     IF output = 1 then
        DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE( 'c column'||i );
        k:=false;
     END IF;
     i:=i+1;
     IF i = 100 then
        k:=false;
     END IF;
END LOOP;
END;
/
```

Comment: Only one problem: if no_data_found is raised, the value of `output` that it had previously will be retained. You need to reset `output` in the exception handler.

Answer (score 1):

You can use:

```
SELECT CASE
       WHEN EXISTS (
              SELECT 1
              FROM   X_TAB
              WHERE  dynamic_column_name = 'FISCAL_NOTE_NFE'
            )
       THEN 1
       ELSE 0
       END
FROM   DUAL
```

It will never throw the exception as it will always return exactly one row.

You can use it like:

```
DECLARE
  i      INT := 0;
  output INT;
BEGIN
  FOR k IN 1 .. 100 LOOP
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE( 'c column -->'||k );
    EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'SELECT CASE WHEN EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM X_TAB WHERE  c'||k||' = ''FISCAL_NOTE_NFE'') THEN 1 ELSE 0 END FROM DUAL'
      INTO output;
    IF output = 1 THEN
      DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE( 'c column'||k );
      i := k;
      EXIT;
    END IF;
  END LOOP;
  -- Do something with i
END;
/
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also use 
`select count(1) from X_TAB`